# ssrs mapping chart colors to a category

Tags: reporting-services, charts, vbscript

I have a pie chart and a bar chart that I use to display some data.  I want to map colors in the charts to specific colors to departments.
The code runs without error but the colors are not always mapped to the same department.

This function is in the body of the report in the 'Code' section:

```
Private mapping As New System.Collections.Hashtable()  
Private colorPalette As String() = {"#5badff", "#8c001a", "#a33247", "#ba6675", "#d199a3", "#e8ccd1"}  
Private boardNames As String() = {"Dept1", "Dept2", "App", "IT", "Delivery", "Development"}  

Public Function SetColorsToBoard()
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim name As String = ""

    IF colorPalette.Length = boardNames.Length Then
        For Each name in boardNames         
            mapping.Add(name, colorPalette(count))
            count = count + 1
        Next
    End If
End Function

Public Function GetColor(ByVal groupingValue As String) As String  
   If mapping.ContainsKey(groupingValue) Then  
        Return mapping(groupingValue)  
    End If  
    Call SetColorsToBoard 
End Function
```

If there is data for Dept1, the colors are displayed as expected.  When I select a different company and they do not have a Dept1 in the query, Dept2 is set to the first color.
As I tried to write the function so that it is not dependent on data.

The `GetColor` function is called in the **Color** section of each chart as an expression.

Why are the mappings dependent on the data returned from the query?

**UPDATE**
I found that my bar chart is stacked.  When I have only 1 dept. in the chart, the first bar is 'blue' which is the first color.  The second bar is burgundy which is the second color.  The Dept. is the Series Grouping.  In this chart there are only 2 dept.  When there are 2 dept, the colors are correct.

Comment: why do not use the expression in ssrs directly to set the color?

Comment: If I do it in code I only have to do it once as opposed to writing the case statement in each chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out...
I needed to add `return mapping(groupingValue)` after the call to set the mappings.
This is the `GetColor` function:

```
Public Function GetColor(ByVal groupingValue As String) As String  
   If mapping.ContainsKey(groupingValue) Then  
        Return mapping(groupingValue)  
    End If  
    Call SetColorsToBoard 
    Return mapping(groupingValue)  
End Function
```